# Toolbar item para selecionar projeto padrão

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Aplicações `Xamarin-Forms` tem opção de selecionar o projeto que quero iniciar `Startup Projects` pela barra de ferramenta conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem como habilitar esta opção para outros projetos, exemplo, tenho uma `solution` com `web-api` e um `console application`, queria poder selecionar o projeto padrão pela `toolbar` e não precisar clicar com botão direito no projeto para defini-lo como padrão.